# SPARQL queries with relational operator

Tags: python, nlp, sparql, dbpedia

I want to use **relational AND/OR operator** onto **SPARQL** queries.

Here query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?dbpedia_link str(?name) as ?label str(?label1) as ?label1 ?freebase_link WHERE {
            ?dbpedia_link rdfs:label ?label1 . 
            ?dbpedia_link foaf:name ?name .
            {
                { ?dbpedia_link rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Film .}
                UNION
                { ?dbpedia_link rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Person .}
            }
            ?dbpedia_link owl:sameAs ?freebase_link .
            FILTER regex(?freebase_link, "^http://rdf.freebase.com") .
            FILTER (lang(?label1) = 'en'). 
            ?name bif:contains "Akshay_Kumar" . 
            ?dbpedia_link dcterms:subject ?sub 
        }
```

In this query, I have used **Akshay_Kumar** which is single name. Now I want that, how can I **use place multiple names at once using relational AND/OR operator**. In short, how can we use **relational operators in sparql**.

Executing sparql query URL : http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Conjunction

*AND* is easy.  If you want to say that X is related to both Y by property P and to Z by property Q, you just include both triples:

```
X P Y .
X Q Z .
```

That can be abbreviated:

X P Y ;
  Q Z .

Now, if the properties are the same, so that you're saying X is related to Y and Z by property P, it becomes:

```
X P Y ;
  P Z .
```

SPARQL provides a shorthand for that (and it's shared with the Turtle serialization of RDF):

```
X P Y, Z .
```

### Disjunction

*OR* is a bit more complicated, but you've already shown one way of doing it.  If you want to say that X is related to *either* Y or Z, you can do:

```
{ X P Y } UNION { X P Z }
```

SPARQL 1.1 includes `VALUES` which can make this a bit simpler:

```
VALUES ?xpValue { Y Z }
X P ?xpValue
```

### Updating Your Query

Your query actually isn't legal SPARQL 1.1 (or SPARQL), even though Virtuoso (the endpoint that DBpedia runs) accepts it.  You can test with [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html).  Also note that you're using `bif:contains`, which provides a string containment function, but SPARQL 1.1 actually provides a [contains](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains) function that you can use.  It also provides [strstarts](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strstarts) which you can use to recognize freebase links a bit more efficiently.  It also provides [langMatches](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-langMatches), which is the correct way to check the language tags of strings. Using those, I'd rewrite your query like the following, which finds resources whose names contain "John" or "Mary". (The limit is just to keep the results short for this example.)

```
select ?resource ?name ?label ?freebase where {
  values ?type { dbpedia-owl:Film dbpedia-owl:Person }
  values ?namePart { "John" "Mary" }

  ?resource rdfs:label ?label ;
            foaf:name ?name ;
            a ?type ;
            owl:sameAs ?freebase .

  filter ( langMatches( lang(?label), 'en' ) &&
           strstarts(str(?freebase), "http://rdf.freebase.com" ) &&
           contains( ?name, ?namePart ) )
}
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fresource%20%3Fname%20%3Flabel%20%3Ffreebase%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Ftype%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3AFilm%20dbpedia-owl%3APerson%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3FnamePart%20%7B%20%22John%22%20%22Mary%22%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Fresource%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3Aname%20%3Fname%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20%3Ftype%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Ffreebase%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28%20langMatches%28%20lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%20%29%20%26%26%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20strstarts%28str%28%3Ffreebase%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Frdf.freebase.com%22%20%29%20%26%26%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20contains%28%20%3Fname%2C%20%3FnamePart%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Your SPARQL query is running good and I have understood the Conjunction and disjunction logic in SPARQL. When I am running this query, it is taking too much time. I want to reduce the execution time for sparql query. How to do that?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it worked for you!  Are you running my query exactly, or something different?  In any case, I think it probably merits a new, separate question.

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply. The query is running good for "John" "Mary" but instead of these if I place "Tom Cruise" "Akshay Kumar" then it takes too much time around 5 second to execute the query. Why sir?

Comment: I don't know if that's actually all that slow.  There is a *lot* of data to consider, after all.  Does changing the order of the filter expressions help at all?

Comment: Ya, I know that but we have our local database for dbpedia data. We are using offline to query on the dbpedia database. Even though, it is taking time. If you have any solution then please share it to me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If above code will not work then change **dbpedia-owl** with `dbo`